# Table is mutating trigger/function may not see it

Tags: oracle, function, triggers

I have a trigger TRG1 before insert or update on table T1 and a function F1 to update the table T1. I'm calling the function F1 from Trigger TRG1. i.e

```
Trigger code:
IF inserting OR updating THEN
  F1(:oldvalue1,:oldvalue2,:newvalue1);
END IF;

Function:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION F1(val1 in varchar2,val2 in varchar2,val3 in varchar2)
) RETURN CHAR IS
BEGIN
    update T1 set col1='A' where col2=val1 and col2=val2 and col3=val3;
END;
```

I'm trying to test in plsql developer ide for updating the value in T1. After I click the post change button. i'm getting this error *Table T1 is mutating trigger/function may not see it encountered in function f1*

Comment: It the trigger is configered as BEFORE or AFTER?

Comment: Yes sir. 
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER bfo_ins_upd_t1
 BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON T1
 FOR EACH ROW

Comment: Can you change it to After insert?

Comment: I can't change this trigger event. bcoz others are using this trigger. actually there is one validation in function F1 based on the validation i'm updating the table T1. There is two updating on T1 statement in Function F1 if cond satisfied one update will execute else other will execute.

Comment: It will throw this error in the case, you are updating the same table in the trigger. But your case can be simplified if you can just use the function/procedure to fetch the changed values for the col1, col2, and col3 and update it in the trigger itself using `:new.col := val`

Comment: Yes. Its working. Thanks. I removed the update statement and assigned the value.

Comment: @Popeye  I am building a trigger to delete a row in the same table on which the trigger is created. Can it be done? the idea is to have a delete record column with true- false value in it.